# Can I use the Google Maps API in PhoneGap without whitelisting the google domains?

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to use the Google Maps API in a PhoneGap application without whitelisting the domains like:

```
<key>ExternalHosts</key>
<array>
<string>maps.google.com</string>
<string>maps.gstatic.com</string>
<string>maps.googleapis.com</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you are using the Google Maps JavaScript API, then it will try to communicate with Google servers via the webview and thus issue requests to Google servers. You *must* whitelist the domains, then.

An alternative would be to use a native maps phonegap plugin (such as MapKit), which would create a MapView in your app and presumably get around the whitelist restriction.